# Send several parameters when combo box activated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

```
self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.on_combo_activated)
```

At the moment when a combo box gets selected only the value of the combo box gets passed on to the function on_combo_activated.

How would I do if I wanted to send another two variables?

Comment: explain better Please

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a fairly simple question with a simple answer, but we don't have context, so no one can answer.

Comment: Basically, when a user changes the value of a combo box, I want to call a function that takes 3 parameters, the value of the combo box, "stringparameter1", and "stringparameter2".

Comment: @eyllanesc  does that make it clearer?

Comment: @ZeZe. What are the other parameters? Are they constant values, or are they generated dynamically?

Comment: @ZeZe Check my answer  :P

Comment: The parameters are constant values, strings in this case.

Comment: In that case, you can just do `.connect(lambda text: self.on_combo_activated(text, 'str1', 'str2'))`.

Comment: PS: another alternative is to use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: @ekhumoro works perfectly! Answer with post and I'll give you the correct answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is by using a `lambda` function:

```
self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(
    lambda text: self.on_combo_activated(text, 'str1', 'str2'))
...

def on_combo_activated(self, text, arg1, arg2):
    print(text, arg1, arg2)
```

The [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function does something similar, but it can sometimes be awkward to use it with positional arguments. If you used it to connect the above slot like this:

```
self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(
    partial(self.on_combo_activated, 'str1', 'str1')
```

the slot would actually print `str1 str2 text`, because extra positional arguments are always *appended*, rather than inserted. However, with keyword arguments, it would work as expected:

```
self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(
    partial(self.on_combo_activated, arg1='str1', arg2='str1'))
```

This last approach might be preferred over the others as it is self-documenting, and therefore perhaps more readable.